# TextField strange behavior when changing cursor position

Tags: flutter, dart

When I write something in the TextField (it's a multiline TextField) and try to change the cursor position it works just fine, but when i put one of those: `,` `-` `(` `:` `"` (and some others) it's behavior changes to (instead of changing cursor position) selecting the text from where it was to where I wanted it to change places to.

[Video that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrcFS.jpg)

Code for the TextField:

```
TextField _newNoteInputField() {
    return TextField(
      controller: newNoteInputController,
      cursorColor: AppColors.gray3,
      maxLines: 6,
      minLines: 1,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: AppColors.newNoteInputFieldText,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
        hintText: 'New Note...',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: AppColors.newNoteInputFieldHint,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tested it out a bit and realized that:

- when it is normal it has that blue thing under the cursor (in this select mode it's not there)
- it only had this problem when you write one of those characters (if you copy/paste it it's completely fine)

I'm a complete beginner, been writing Flutter for a week and it's my first programming language, so I don't know if it's something I missed but I really couldn't find anything anywhere.
I searched flutter documentation, GitHub issues and in here and found nothing that helped.

Comment: What is your flutter version?

Comment: @AkbarMasterpadi Flutter 3.0.4